# Function continuous only at irrational point.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, irrational-numbers

Let $r_{1}, r_{2},...$ be an enumeration of rational in $[0,1].$ For $n=1, 2,..$ let

$$t_{n}(x)=0, (0\leq x < r_{n})$$

$$t_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{n^2}, (r_{n}\leq x \leq 1)$$

and define

$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}t_{n}(x)$$

Then $f$ is continuous at all irrational points.

How can i approach this kind of question? how to think? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If $y$ is irrational and if $\varepsilon>0$, then there is a natural $N$ such that$$\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}<\varepsilon.$$Then$$(\forall x\in[0,1]):\left\lvert f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^Nt_n(x)\right\rvert=\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty t_n(x)<\varepsilon.$$So, we have a series of functions, each of which is continuous at $y$, which converges uniformly to $f$. Therefore, $f$ is continuous at $y$

Comment: How is the irrationality of $y$ relevant? It seems you could just pick $N > n$ (together with the summation condition) to get continuity at the n-th rational $y$.

Comment: @Ned I used the irrationalty of $y$ when I stated that I have a setries of functions each of which is continuous at $y$. This is false for that rational numbers; for each rational $q\in[0,1]$, there is a natural $n$ such that $t_n$ is discontinuous at $q$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos more important $t_n$ is discontinuous at $q$ for **every** $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @user251257 No, it is not. *Each* $t_n$ is discontinuous at a single point.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos ah. My bad. I meant the partial sum. You are right

Comment: @user251257 Now, let us see if the OP agrees with me.

Comment: It might be more clear, if you "just" apply uniform limit theorem on the partial sum $f_N = \sum_{n=1}^N t_n$ on $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @user251257.Right. Because if $x=r_n$ then the $N$th partial sum is not continuous at $x$ for $N\geq n.$ But if $x\in [0,1]\setminus \Bbb Q$ then  the $N$th partial sum is constant on a nbhd of $x.$